# ACPI exception: could not find/resolve named package element: AMD 3(dspkginit-381)

Tags: fedora, kernel, boot, hardware, amd-graphics

I am continuously facing problems one after another, first I had this [problem on Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416447/end-kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0) I didn't got solution so I installed fedora and deleted Ubuntu. Now on booting I get this[image]. After startup it shows error that:

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/bmlinuz-4.14.13-300.fc27.x86_64 crashed,
```

in its description it shows that this is hardware problem not software. I am having **AMD RADEON Graphics**.

I think this is making my system slow while doing tasks.

P.S. This is a Lenovo notebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In  your error message, that is a known ACPI firmware bug, that generates the error _SB.PCxxx and it affects several operating systems besides Linux. It affects FreeBSD and OpenBSD too, for instance.

Upgrade to the latest BIOS for your model from the Lenovo official site.

Comment: yes it is Lenovo , Is this depends upon OS on Lenovo site it is given for Windows but I am having fedora

Comment: @Debian  I am afraid I wont be able to help you how to update it. Maybe installing Windows in an USB pen.